# Visual Studio Code won't compile or submit USQL script

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am using Visual Studio Code (VS Code) to compile and then submit `usql` scripts on our Azure platform.

Something happend and I cannot compile or submit any usql jobs anymore, with following error message:
[image]

I tried multiple solutions to fix it:

- Reinstall visual studio code
- Updated to the latest version (1.38)
- Reinstall the Azure Data Lake Tools package
- Remove all generated folders and files and start from scratch
- I made sure this is not access-related (I can run jobs on Azure web portal)
- The script does not have any bugs and it is supposed to run (checked on Azure web portal)

I work on MS Windows VM x64, VS Code version 1.38.

I am completely puzzled by that, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, it did not solve the issue. Mysteriously, after latest update (1.38.1) it works again.

Comment: i suppose that it's bug in some versions of sdk.I summarized it in my answer. If you don't concern,you could accept that for others' reference on the forum. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue on my side. I follow steps in this detailed [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-tools-for-vscode-local-run-and-debug#set-up-the-u-sql-local-run-environment) and it works well for me.

Since you already sorted out several possible issues, I would suggest you checking if you missed some installations follow above link. In particular, the following steps:

- 2.1 To install BuildTools, click visualcppbuildtools_full.exe in the LocalRunDependency folder, then follow the wizard instructions.
- 2.2 To install Win10SDK 10240, click sdksetup.exe in the LocalRunDependency/Win10SDK_10.0.10240_2 folder, then follow the
  wizard instructions.
- And and run `ADL: Start Local Run Service.`

Just for summary, it works after updating sdk version to 1.38.1.